# Do anyone have implemented unlimited paging CViewGrid?

Tags: ajax, facebook, twitter, yii, paging

I want to implement unlimited records paging, like Twitter and Facebooks feeds, when someone reach on last record their we should show a button LOAD MORE or MORE .. by that we fetch more records time to time, is any widget available like this? I search on different places but nobody did this think in yii.. If anyone saw somewhere or have any simple example to do this please share .. will be really thankful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [yiinfinite-scroll](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll)?

Comment: yes some kind of this.. but it replace previous records .. I want some thing like Facebook and Twitter, like they maintain previous records as well ..

Comment: ahhh yes it is working as i want .. that was my mistake to implement this .. many many thanks buddy .. :)

Comment: Is facebook like and share working for you?? 
I use the same plugin but facebook like is not loading in ajax call.